# Adding Forum software integration to Symfony2

Tags: symfony, forum, mybb

Does anyone know if theres a way to integrate a forum such as mybb into symfony?

I want to have a central location where the Users information is stored.

Answer (score 1):

**FriendsOfSymfony / FOSCommentBundle** https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle

or

**FriendsOfSymfony / FOSMessageBundle** https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle

You need to write your own templates but the functionality is great